# Show that angle BOC is $0.691$ radians

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, modular-arithmetic

[image]

What i tried.

Since we are given the gradient of $AC$ is $\frac{9}{25}$, thus length $AO$ is $3.15/9*25=8.75$ while length $AC$ is $9.299$ by Pythagoras theorem. Next i can find angle $CAO$ using the trigonometric formula which gives 36.23 rad. Angle ACO can then be found next.

I unsure how to continue from here. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

- After you found $\angle ACO$, use the property that $OBPC$ is a sector, and hence we know that $\angle CBO= \angle ACO$.
- Use the property that angles in $\triangle CBO$ sums up to $\pi$.

Remark:

- We do not need length information to find the angle.

Comment: To find angle $ACO$, we still have use the length information and the gradient?

Comment: $\angle ACO = \arctan \left( \frac{25}9\right)$. We do not have to use the height.

Comment: Okay thanks, I understood already.

Comment: Could u help me with this question also. Thanks https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847240/calculate-angle-dpa-congruent-and-similar-triangles